# Is it possible to call a function/procedure from Power BI Desktop report to fetch value from database based on the filters applied during run time?

Tags: oracle, report, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am new to the Power BI. I am trying to build a report in Power BI with source as the Oracle tables. As part of the report, I need to fetch a measure from a table [which was not part of the tables used in the model] based on the filters applied at the run time in the report. Is it possible to call a function / procedures at the run time from Power BI? In case of functions, it can return only one value, I need to call the function for all available records.

Please note that the table from which I am going to fetch the measure can't be joined in the base model [on top of which report is built] with other tables used on the report. So I am checking the feasibility to fetch values at run time. Is this something possible in Power BI?

Thanks for your suggestion and guidance.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, a direct query / live connection might work. Other than that, I think the answer is no. Can you explain your end goal a bit more? There may be a different work around.

Comment: To generate something at run time you need to use `DAX`. `Dax` can only refer to data that already exists. Generally speaking, Power BI can only use data that exists (i.e. a view or a table). AFAIK there is no way to fetch data based on parameters at runtime. The workaround is to call the function with _every_ value, make that a table and refer to it.

Comment: This appears to one of many approaches but it's really not recommended. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-do-I-pass-parameters-to-my-SQL-statement/td-p/118716